# Excel formula - count if particular value is present only in the weekend

Tags: excel, formula, weekday

I have the below file in excel.

**Edit:**

This will be the new image

[image: Excel image 2]

- If Name1/2/3 has either A1/A2(only these 2 values) in the weekend columns then I have to add **1** in the **ANS** column.
- If Name1/2/3 has other than A1/A2 like H then it should not be added in the **ANS** column.
- It must consider only the weekend. Weekdays are not at all considered.
- So, As I mentioned in the **ANS** column,

  1) For Name 1, the count should be 4(only A1/A2 is present in the weekends)

  2) For Name 2, the count should be 3(only A1/A2 is counted, one H is omitted)

  3) For Name 2, the count should be 2(only A1/A2 is counted, both H is omitted)

Comment: So what would be the result in your example? 4?

Comment: If you just want to count the arguments (not-empty cells) in a Range, then you should use a COUNTA-formula:  =COUNTA(A3:I3)

Comment: Now showing the picture.  Grammar.

Comment: @MarcoVos only works if the cells are truly empty and not some formula like =if(or(weekday(A1)=1,weekday(A1)=7),"A","")

Comment: would you ever have character under Monday to Friday range without having character on the weekend, and if so should the answer be 0?  what if only A and C are mentioned, do you still count the characters?  It the difference between AND and OR for a logical statement.  Do you need A and B and C and D  in order to count characters, or do you need A or B or C or D to count characters?  Can you have more than 1 character in a cell?

Comment: Hope now the question is clear:).@Macro @ Forward

Answer (score 0):

this will count both blank cell and cells containing ""

```
=countif(A3:I3,"")
```

So since you know there are 9 columns to check:

```
=9-countif(A3:I3,"")
```

Comment: And to count the non-blank cells: =COUNTIF(A3:I3,"<>"&"")